# How to add pydantic serialization/deserialization support for a foreign (third-party) class?

Tags: python, pydantic

Consider a third-party class that doesn't support pydantic serialization, and you're not under control of the source code of that class, i.e., you cannot make it inherit from `BaseModel`. Let's assume the entire state of that class can be constructed and obtained via its public interface (but the class may have private fields). So in theory we'd be able to write serialization/deserialization functions of that class based on its public interface.

Is it somehow possible to use such a class inside a pydantic `BaseModel`? I.e., the goal would be to somehow arrive at:

```py
class MySerializableClass(BaseModel):
    foreign_class_instance: ForeignClass
```

How could we add serialization/deserialization functions to properly support the `foreign_class_instance` field?

---

As a concrete let's take for instance a Numpy array as an example of a foreign class that we want to support. By serializing/deserializing based on the "public interface" I mean:

- For serialization we can use the public interface of `np.array` to get its data including meta data like dtype and shape. The output of the serialization function could be something like `{"dtype": "int", "shape": [3], "data": [1, 2, 3]}` (or any other composition of JSON-serializable data). The serialization function would have a signature like `serialize(x: np.ndarray) -> object` (for lack of the `JsonData` type).
- The deserialization function would get this serialized representation, and would construct the `np.ndarray` instance again on the public interface of `np.ndarray`, which typically means using its constructor. The signature would be the inverse: `deserialize(o: object) -> np.ndarray`.

My question is: Assuming I can implement these two `serialize` and `deserialize` functions just fine like in this example, how can I integrate them into pydantic so that serializing/deserializing a `BaseModel` implicitly makes use of the two functions.

Comment: @python_user: I don't think this is possible due to the synthesized `__init__` generated by pydantic, which prevents calling the proper constructor of the foreign class, right? Another issue is that there may be a collisions of the fields of the foreign class and `BaseModel`.

Comment: This is too abstract. Please give a concrete example of what you mean by _"public interface"_. Do you mean class-namespace **annotations**? What about methods and instance attributes? The entire concept of a "field" is something that is inherent to dataclass-types (incl. Pydantic models), and **not** inherent to "normal" classes. In fact, please provide a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including such a not-Pydantic class and the desired result to show in a simplified way what you would like to get.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Sorry for the confusion. I didn't mean based on annotations. I've added an specific example to the question. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Not to be pedantic here (no pun intended), but rather than writing more prose, a simple code snippet showing what you mean/want would be much clearer. That is why I suggested a MRE. Aside from that: If I understand correctly, in your example you want a field of type `ndarray` on a Pydantic model in such a way that allows complete instantiation from raw JSON (as well as from a dictionary in pure Python) on the one hand and dumping (to JSON as well as again a dictionary) on the other. And more broadly for this to be possible with arbitrary types?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I've made the experience that if you want to see a general solution/pattern it can be detrimental to be too specific. Often people just focus on the specific problem at hand instead of looking at the big picture. In that sense the two lines of code given were already the **minimal** reproducible example. I left out the details of what `ForeignClass` is on purpose to not distract from the actual question. I'm not at all interested in the specifics of solving this for `ndarray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the process of defining **custom field types** is described in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#custom-data-types).

The **bare minimum** is a method called `__get_validators__` returning an iterator of validation methods, the last of which *should* return an instance of that custom type. That means with third-party classes you will almost certainly need to subclass (or monkey-patch) them.

If the type you are dealing with has no built-in JSON serialization support (types like `str` or `list` for example are supported out of the box), you also need to sepcify *how* instances of that type are supposed to be dumped to JSON. This can be done selectively, when calling the `json` method or configured model-wide via the [`json_encoders`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) dictionary.

The example of the Numpy `ndarray` is *slightly* more involved because we need to

1. define a sensible [basic constructor](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) for our subclass and
2. decide what type of data we want to support during parsing/validation.

A very simple setup might look like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator, Mapping
from typing import Any

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SerializableNDArray(np.ndarray[Any, Any]):
    def __new__(cls, array_like: ArrayLike) -> SerializableNDArray:
        return np.asarray(array_like).view(cls)

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: Any) -> SerializableNDArray:
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            return cls(np.array(**v))
        return cls(v)

    def json_dump(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return {"object": self.tolist(), "dtype": str(self.dtype)}


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: SerializableNDArray

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            SerializableNDArray: SerializableNDArray.json_dump
        }
```

Here is a little demo:

```py
def main() -> None:
    test_json_1 = '{"a": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]}'
    test_json_2 = '{"a": {"object": [[1, 2], [3, 4]], "dtype": "float32"}}'
    obj1 = Model.parse_raw(test_json_1)
    obj2 = Model.parse_raw(test_json_2)
    print(obj1.json(indent=4))
    print(obj2.json(indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```json
{
    "a": {
        "object": [
            1.0,
            2.0,
            3.0
        ],
        "dtype": "float64"
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "a": {
        "object": [
            [
                1.0,
                2.0
            ],
            [
                3.0,
                4.0
            ]
        ],
        "dtype": "float32"
    }
}
```

Notice that I decided to make the JSON representation of our custom array type *always* be an object with the keys `object` and `dtype` instead of simply an array of numbers because this allows us to preserve more information (in this example the data type) and the validator accepts a mapping that can be unpacked into the [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) function. (So those keys need to be a subset of the parameter names of that function.)

I left out the shape deliberately here because it is not a parameter of `numpy.array`. The shape is inferred from the way the "array-like" object passed to that function is structured (`list` of `list`s for example).

If the data to validate is not some kind of mapping, the validator will always to try to coerce the value directly via our constructor, i.e. via [`numpy.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html). That should give type errors that are nice enough, when invalid data is parsed.

Obviously you could design this very differently. You could use a different constructor or a totally different validator that allows you to e.g. pass data that can be unpacked into the [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function instead (there you could use `shape` for example). Or you could decide that dumping it simply as an array of numbers is sufficient for your needs. This is just an example, but I think it illustrates the approach.